# Declaring multiple objects of different classes with the same name

Tags: c++, scope, declaration

Is it OK for me to declare multiple objects with the same name, but in different classes? Or will this throw everything into chaos? Let me include some code to help understand what I want to do:

```
class get{
    public:
        string info(){
            int str; cin >> str;
            return str;
        };
};
class store{
    public:
        string data;
}

int main(){
    get foo;
    store foo;

    foo.data = foo.info();

    cout << foo.data;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this isn't necessarily the code that I'm using, just an example. If I need to elaborate, please tell me. Thanks, all!

Comment: You know you could compile this and find out.  You will see it fail.  BTW why would you want to have multiple variables with the same name?  How would you tell them apart?

Comment: See by yourself: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/81EYDBUYIVqtlZEX

Comment: @NathanOliver Just for organizational purposes. Also, my compiler is on the fritz, I'm searching for a new one.

Comment: No, this will not work. You could however name one variable `Foo` and the other `foo`, since C language is case sensitive. But such code would be considered ugly and would (as you say) throw everything into chaos...

Comment: @Creep2DJ There are plenty of online compilers you can use.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, I just wasn't sure if I was doing it wrong or if I was just an idiot. Thanks for the link, it looks like a half decent one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not declare two objects with the same name in the same scope. The compiler will issue an error.

However for example this code is valid

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class get
{
public:
    std::string info() const 
    {
        std::string str; 
        std::cin >> str;
        return str;
    }
};

class store
{
public:
    std::string data;
};

store foo;

int main()
{
    get foo;

    ::foo.data = foo.info();

    std::cout << ::foo.data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

because two objects with the same name are defined in different scopes and there are used qualified names.

Also you may declare an object wuth the same name as the name of a class in the same scope. For example

```
store store;
```

In this case the name of the object hides the name of the class.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much, this is definitely going to help.